# Linq To Sql Insert Issue

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am using `Linq To Sql` to insert few data to a table in `Sql server 2008`.

```
            memadd.add_id = Convert.ToDecimal(resadd);
            memadd.mem_add = txtResAdd.Text;
            memadd.tel_no1 =Convert.ToDecimal(txtResTelNo.Text);
            memadd.mob_no1 = Convert.ToDecimal(txtResMobNo.Text);
            memadd.state = drpResState.Text;
            memadd.city = drpResCity.Text;
            memadd.pin_no = Convert.ToDecimal(txtResPinNo.Text);
            dt.mem_addresses.InsertOnSubmit(memadd);
            dt.SubmitChanges();
```

My issue here is that when i insert data into the field , it gives me an error saying

```
Can't perform Create, Update or Delete operations on 'Table(mem_address)' because it has no primary key.
```

I have a situation wherein i cant set primary key to that table .Can anyone please point me out what needs to be done here.
Thanks

Comment: Why is it that you can't set a primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell the `memadd` table in the DBML designer to select `add_id` as a PK for example.

It needs not be on the database itself.

Comment: if i do that the add_id is going to be repeated like 1,2,3 then again 1,2,3 ,,, so do you think it would be feasible , doing that wont create problems ????

Comment: @freebird: Make it a composite key then to find some form of uniqueness.

Comment: ,, can i set add_id as primary key in the designer and carry on or i should proceed as you suggested.. I dont know how to make it composite key.

Comment: @freebird: Just select both columns.

Answer (score 1):

Linq to sql can't be used in such situations. Just warp your insert statement into a stored procedure and add the procedure to your data model. If you can't do that, write a normal function with a bit of in-line SQL

Comment: IIRC, I had no problem providing Linq2SQL with a 'pseudo' PK.

Answer (score 1):

Linq does not support table w/o primary keys...